# Use of string in if() statement django error: string as left operand, not QuerySet

Tags: python, django, if-statement, for-loop

So, I am getting an error of:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not QuerySet
```

I have a method which has:

```
error_val = self.error_object
    for p in self.output:
        request = requests.get(p, timeout=settings.REQUESTS_TIMEOUT, verify=False)   
        for req in request:
            if error_val in req:
                print 'error Found in'+req
```

This error is happening due to `error_val` in the `if()`

In laymen's terms, this is basically saying (if I'm not mistaken), `"Whoah, I'm getting a object value, with strings, but I can't compare to another object value"`

`req` - is basically the html output of a page e.g. `<html><body><!--html content here--></body></html>`

`error_val` - is an variable holding the values of an object (results from a django query)

**My question**: how can I rework this method so, I can use the `error_val` var against each `req` (request)?

Any help, comments, suggestions are really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: What about Entry.objects.values_list() instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.error_object` holds the instance of `QuerySet` class. And **no** you can't check if object of this type is inside the string.

`QuerySet` is a class which is a wrapper for Django ORM query/ies. It implements `iterable` protocol so you can iterate over it to get matching `Model` instances one by one.
Then you can access the fields of these instances as normal object attributes. If one of them is a string then you can check if it's a substring of `req`.
It's hard to say, what exactly you are trying to do but just a guess:

```
for model_instance in self.error_object:
    for req in request:
        if model_instance.some_string_field in req:
             print 'error Found in' + req
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was wondering how one might go about using iterable protocol here?

Comment: `for model_instance in self.error_object:` and then just access it's field with `model_instance.some_field`

Comment: if you may have seen though, `req` is not a `model instance` its a `request` with `requests` lib which outputs some html output. Only `self.error_object` is coming from a `django model` . Does that make sense?

Comment: I've never said that `req` is a model instance.

Comment: How can I check an instance of a `req` (and instance in the loop of `request`) to see if it has `self.error_object` in it? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Once again: `error_object` is a `QuerySet` instance. It can't be in a string. Result of the query can return from `0 to n` model instances. You have to get model instances from it i.e. by iterating over it.

Comment: Appreciate your patience here. How can I `.iterate()` over though?

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for the help. Still getting my bearings straight with for() loops in python, especially when interacting with django querysets.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to check whether any of multiple objects' string representations appear in your response (I am unable to figure out what other behavior "queryset in string" might be intended to create) you want something like:

```
error_strings = [str(val) for val in self.error_object]
...
# then in your loop
if any(val in req for val in error_strings):
```

You might also profile creating an `or`d together regexp of error strings.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance here, but would creating a regex here hurt performance?

Comment: Regex is useful when you are looking for strings matching the pattern. If you're looking for the exact substring of a string, then regex is not a good choice.